# VS2010 Resource Images NOT purging from project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, image, resources

After removing images from a project using the Resources window's "Remove Resources", my images still remain in the Solution Explorer.

Why is that?  And how can I "safely" remove them?  I've tried doing this manually one at a time but it requires me to SHOW my mainform in Design Mode to see if VS2010 crashes on me and then "undoing" what I did.

There's got to be an easier way.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of project is the one with the resources? C#, VB.NET. C++? Windows Forms, WPF, MFC, Winapi or something else?

Comment: Have you tried going to the project properties, Resources section, and deleting from there?

Comment: Sorry I omitted that in my original question (oversight)

Comment: Yes.  The images get removed from the Resources container window.  But when I look in the Resources nodes in my Solution, they are still there.  They never truly get purged.

Answer (score 1):

Try a full manual deletion:

- Delete the property that accesses the resource from .Resources.Designer.cs. It should look like this (if the resource were called `btnAdd`):

  ```
  internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap btnAdd {
      get {
          object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("btnAdd", resourceCulture);
          return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
      }
  }
  ```
- Delete the reference to the resource from the .resx file. Should look like this:

  ```
  <data name="btnAdd" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\..\..\..\..\Icons\CurrentIcons\btnAdd.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  ```
- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, Unload it, edit it and look for something like this (and delete it).

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="btnAdd.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

Comment: Code markup nested inside lists is a bit funny - you need to indent 8 times instead of 4 to make it happen and the button on the toolbar still only does 4. (See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of work. I will give it a try with the belief that this will indeed do the trick.  I guess this must be a bug in VS2010 and I wonder if anyone else knows about it.  Thanks for answering my question even though it still requires a manual process.

Comment: Try it for just one, and if it works, you can do it quickly using Find and Replace with regular expressions